# Pyspark: How to filter 10000 random elements from spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I extract a random sample of 10000 elements from my spark DataFrame?

I need something like sample function in Pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using `randomSplit`. The result will be approximate though. You might not get exactly 10000 rows but it will be close enough

```
import pandas as pd
totalrows = 40000
df = pd.DataFrame([["name_"+str(i) for i in range(totalrows)], list(range(totalrows))]).transpose()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

def random_sampler(X, totalrows, nrows=100, seed = 42):
    split_ratios = [nrows/totalrows, 1-(nrows/totalrows)]
    random_sampled_data = X.randomSplit([split_ratio for split_ratio in split_ratios], seed=seed)
    return random_sampled_data[0]


random_sampler(sdf, totalrows, nrows=10000, seed = 42).count()
# 9952
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by using [randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=randomsplit#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit)